# Building data structure for Dictionary

Tags: java, data-structures

I am looking for some high level thoughts/ideas help me building a data structure for Dictionary.  I have a legacy 'product (medicine) search system' which is very slow and complex in nature. We would need to completely re-architect the system for efficient and maintainable solution.

To simplify the question, I take an example of 'Dictionary' ( I expect my new system behaves like Dictionary )

1. I should be able to store Word,description and few synonyms ( equivalent generic medicine),
2. Words should not duplicate
3. Synonyms will also be instance of Word ( it should carry behaviour of word, description and synonyms).
4. Faster searching

UseCases

1. When a word is searched, its meaning and synonyms displayed
2. Faster Search
3. Removal of synonym should be possible
4. Adding new word, should be able to add to any existing word's synonyms

I created a data structure shown below

```
Class Word {
    String meaning;
    List<Word> synonyms;
}
```

To store Words, I am thinking to use  `TreeSet`

because

> TreeSet provides an implementation of the Set interface that uses a
>   tree for storage. Objects are stored in sorted, ascending order.
>   Access and retrieval times are quite fast, which makes TreeSet an
>   excellent choice when storing large amounts of sorted information that
>   must be found quickly.

Or I can use `HashMap`, where the hashcode of word and synonyms word instance made equal which could enable faster retrieval.

Still I could see lot of challenges

1. When ever new word is added how to link with its synonyms
2. Look up would be slow when there are huge number of words
3. Editing  word also should reflect synonyms and vice versa

Any thoughts/inputs/tricks would be highly valued

Comment: I have built such a system in the real world. Words are *not* unique. The same spelling can have multiple forms (verb, noun, adjective, etc) or the same form (noun) but multiple independent meanings where each of these meanings would have their own set of synonyms. Words can have alternate spellings. In practice, you need multiple levels: one for pure spellings, one for word types, one for specific word senses. At the bottom-most level you can add some of your concerns (linking to synonyms, for example).

Comment: How do you want to search for a word? Why use a `TreeSet` instead of a `HashSet` if you don't care about ordering? Why do synonyms need to be a `Word` as well, by definition they share their `meaning` with parent `Word`?

Comment: Updated question with use cases, and TreeSet should be faster retrieval than HashSet.

Comment: I am mainly looking for some general ideas(not any code) which may help me to build efficient system. Comments,opinion, links , references are ideally what I looking for. I will consolidate my findings here once I finalize the architecture -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For word search and word completion requirement [Trie](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie&ei=bTmTUvjTBYiIrQeu2IHADQ&usg=AFQjCNEIcyShNtanyShhRfB9XU5VqI6VNA&sig2=mBfp2apTxZCKFDi7XDc0tw&bvm=bv.56988011,d.bmk) would be a fast alternative. Take a look at `Java implementations`:

> In computer science, a trie, also called digital tree and sometimes
>   radix tree or prefix tree (as they can be searched by prefixes), is an
>   ordered tree data structure that is used to store a dynamic set or
>   associative array where the keys are usually strings.

http://pathakalgo.blogspot.in/2012/11/trie-data-structure-implementation-in.html

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Trie&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&oq=Trie&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.856j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

For synonym linkage, you can maintain a `Map<String, LinkedList<String>>`. Once a word is found using `Trie`, fetching associated sysnonyms would be O(1).

Comment: `Trie` is excellent, but I was looking for same node(word) is referenced at different level ( opposite to concept of tree) - I am afraid that becomes too messy

Comment: I agree with you , I should be able to extend the `Trie` algorithm to match my requirement (Storing  synonym )

Comment: Yep, that is what I was trying to look for.. I think finding one solutions for two distinct requirements wouldn't result in a simple implementation. If you can decouple `synonym` list from `word` object, things would be less messy IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Dictionary_representation) to store all words in dictionary. Add a list of synonims for each word (node).